# Should asking about going the opposite direction be a separate question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

I asked a question recently, *[How can I create an Image in GDI+ from a Base64-Encoded string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746855/how-can-i-create-an-image-in-gdi-from-a-base64-encoded-string-in-c)*, which got a response that led me to the answer. I accepted the leading response and posted the code I came up with as the answer.

Now I need to go the opposite direction (I have a GDI+ Image and I need to get its contents into a Base64 string) and due to the nature of the process, it's not a straightforward reversal of steps, so I'd like to ask SO for more help.

Should I update the original question to include an "and vice versa"? Or should I create a new question? And if I revise the original question, what should I do about the answer I already accepted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be a separate question - the issues involved may be quite different. For example, "how do I climb Everest?" is different from "how do I ski down it?"

Comment: Done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830622/how-can-i-create-a-base64-encoded-string-from-an-gdi-image-in-c

Comment: The answer, if you're smart, to #1 is you don't, and to #2 is that you won't have that problem because you won't be up there in the first place and if you were kidnapped and taken there for whatever reason, you wouldn't have skis. So there are no issues involved here. :P

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Neil.  The only thing I would add here, is that I have found the answer (far to often!) to my questions by googling the keywords in the question title.

I am much more likley to type in google:

- c++ Create GDI+ Image Base64
- c++ Base64-Encoded GDI+ Image

You've done the right thing by adding a link from question #2 to question #1.  For what its worth, I'd add the link in question #1 too!